# Issue with cudafft library and fftshift on odd image dimensions

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cufft, frequency-domain

'm facing with a code I'm implementing for an exam using the GPU. Specifically, the code I'm writing is in C++, and I'm using the CUFFT library to perform the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT). The purpose of the project is to resize images that have both even and odd dimensions. The current steps I am taking are as follows:

1. Perform FFT with CUFFT.
2. Shift low frequencies to the center of the spectrum.
3. Crop the center of the Fourier spectrum using a square mask with dimensions equal to cropping dimensions of the image.
4. Perform inverse FFT shift.
5. Perform IFFT again with CUFFT.

The problem is: when processing square images with odd dimensions, even without using the GPU kernel for image resizing (executing only steps 1-2-4-5), the resulting image appears with colors that do not correspond to reality. I am attaching the code in which I perform the FFT shift on square images with odd dimensions and the obtained result.

Could someone help me identify the reason behind this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



//bool forward is true in fftshift in forward sense, otherwise is false.
__global__ void fftshift(cufftDoubleComplex *im, int height, int width, bool forward)
{
    int x, y, indshift;
    cufftDoubleComplex c;

    int idy = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //columns
    int idx = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  //rows
    int ind = idx + idy*width; 
    // input sizes
    int sx = width;
    int sy = height;

    // size of top-left quadrant
    int cx = forward ? (sx + 1) / 2 : sx / 2;
    int cy = forward ? (sy + 1) / 2 : sy / 2;

     if(idx < cy && idy < width) 
      {
        if(idx<cy && idy<cx) 
        {
            x=idx+cy;
            y=idy+ cx;
        }
        else if(idx<cy && idy>=cx) 
        {
            x=idx+cy; 
            y=idy- cx;
        }

       indshift = x+y*width;

        c.x = im[ind].x;
        c.y = im[ind].y;

        im[ind].x = im[indshift].x;
        im[ind].y = im[indshift].y;

        im[indshift].x = c.x;
        im[indshift].y = c.y;


    }

}

int main() {
    
    int in_max,in_min;
    cufftHandle planZ2Z, planIZ2Z;
    ofstream fp;

    // Read input image using OpenCV
    cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread("donnaD.jpg", 0);

    if (inputImage.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: Couldn't read the input image." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get input image dimensions
    int inputWidth = inputImage.cols;
    int inputHeight = inputImage.rows;

    
    cufftDoubleComplex* h_input  = (cufftDoubleComplex * )malloc(inputHeight*inputWidth*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));  
    cufftDoubleComplex* h_output  = (cufftDoubleComplex * )malloc(inputHeight*inputWidth*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));  

    cufftPlan2d(&planZ2Z, inputHeight, inputWidth, CUFFT_Z2Z);
    cufftPlan2d(&planIZ2Z, inputHeight, inputWidth, CUFFT_Z2Z);


    // Find minimum and maximum values
    in_max=  static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));
    in_min = static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; ++j) {
            int pixel_value = static_cast<int>(inputImage.at<uchar>(i, j));

            if (pixel_value < in_min) {
                    in_min = pixel_value;
            }

            if (pixel_value > in_max) {
                    in_max = pixel_value;
            }
        }
    }

  printf("height : %d, width %d", inputHeight,inputWidth);
  printf("\nMax value: %d\n",in_max);
  printf("\nMin value: %d\n",in_min);

  fp.open("input_donnaD.txt",ios::out);
  for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; ++i) {
     for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; ++j) {
            fp<< (int)inputImage.at<uchar>(i,j)<<" ";
    }
    fp<<"\n";
  }
  fp.close();

    for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
    {  
        for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
        {
            h_input[i * inputWidth + j].x = (double) inputImage.at<uchar>(i,j);
            h_input[i * inputWidth + j].y = 0.0f;
        
        }
  }

    // Allocate memory for input and padded output on the device
    cufftDoubleComplex* d_input, *d_output, *FI;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_input, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_output, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
    cudaMemset(d_output,0,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    cudaMalloc((void**)&FI, inputWidth * inputHeight * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));
    cudaMemset(FI,0,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex));

    // Copy input data from host to device using cudaMemcpy2D
    cudaMemcpy2D(d_input, inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), h_input, inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), inputWidth * sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), inputHeight, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Define block and grid dimensions
    dim3 blockDim(1, 1); 
    dim3 gridDim;
    gridDim.y = inputHeight/blockDim.y+((inputHeight%blockDim.y)==0? 0:1);
    gridDim.x = inputWidth/blockDim.x+((inputWidth%blockDim.x)==0? 0:1);

    cout<<"gridDim.x: "<<gridDim.x<<" gridDim.y: "<<gridDim.y<<"\n";
    cout<<"blockDim.x: "<<blockDim.x<<" blockDim.y: "<<blockDim.y<<"\n";
 
    // Launch the kernel
    cufftExecZ2Z(planZ2Z, d_input, FI, CUFFT_FORWARD);
    fftshift<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(FI,inputHeight,inputWidth, true);
    fftshift<<<gridDim,blockDim>>>(FI,inputHeight,inputWidth, false);
    cufftExecZ2Z(planIZ2Z, FI, d_output, CUFFT_INVERSE);


  // Copy the result back to the host using cudaMemcpy2D
   cudaMemcpy(h_output,d_output,inputWidth*inputHeight*sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  printf("\nOutput dims of image: (%d,%d) \n",inputHeight,inputWidth);
    

  double max = h_output[0].x;
  double min = h_output[0].x;

  for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
    {
      if(h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x>max)
        max = h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x;
      if(h_output[j+ i*inputWidth].x<min)
         min = h_output[j + i*inputWidth].x;
    }

  }

//print double max and min value
printf("\n\nMax value: %f\n",max);
printf("\nMin value: %f\n",min);


//write the value of output_res in file using fp file descriptor
fp.open("output.txt",ios::out);

for(int i=0;i<inputHeight;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<inputWidth;j++)
        fp<< round((h_output[i*inputWidth+j].x - min) * (in_max - in_min) / (max - min) + 0)<<" ";
        
    fp<<"\n";
} 
//close fp file descriptor
fp.close();


// Convert the padded output to OpenCV Mat for visualization or further processing
cv::Mat outputImage(inputHeight, inputWidth, CV_8UC1);

for (int i = 0; i < inputHeight; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputWidth; ++j) {
        outputImage.at<uchar>(i, j) = round((h_output[i*inputWidth+j].x - min) * (in_max - in_min) / (max - min) + 0);
      }
}

  // Find minimum and maximum values
  in_max=  static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));
  in_min = static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(0, 0));

    for (int i = 0; i < outputImage.rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < outputImage.cols; ++j) {
            int pixel_value = static_cast<int>(outputImage.at<uchar>(i, j));

            if (pixel_value < in_min) {
                    in_min = pixel_value;
            }

            if (pixel_value > in_max) {
                    in_max = pixel_value;
            }
        }
    }

  printf("height : %d, width %d", inputHeight,inputWidth);
  printf("\nMax value: %d\n",in_max);
  printf("\nMin value: %d\n",in_min);


   // Display or save the padded image using OpenCV as needed
   imwrite("output.jpg",outputImage);


    // Cleanup
    delete[] h_input;
    delete[] h_output;
    cudaFree(d_input);
    cudaFree(d_output);
    cudaFree(FI);
    cufftDestroy(planZ2Z);
    cufftDestroy(planIZ2Z);

    return 0;
}
```

Input image - size 301x301:

[image: Input image - size 301x301]

Output image - size 301x301:

[image: Output image - size 301x301]

I would like to obtain the same image as input, but using only the FFT in the forward sense, double FFT shift to adjust the zero frequencies, and inverse FFT the result is wrong.

For the time being, I set aside the initial issue of resizing images as I am already encountering problems with just these steps.

Comment: By the looks of it you have tramped on the DC component for the image and some of the low frequency components as well. Possibly with some overflows on conversion to byte data. You really need to understand the exact format that CUFFT returns the FFT data in. My guess is that for an NxN square image it will return  NxN/2 complex numbers as complex conjugate symmetric where in place transforms store the real DC and alternating components in place. It is easy to muck that up. There isn't much point in shifting the FFT data - most practitioners get used to seeing it with the origin at zero PDQ.

Comment: Hi @MartinBrown in my case I'm using a complex-to-complex transformation, so the output is NxN in the case of a square image. I'm shifting the data because the goal is to resize the image, so I need the zero frequency at the center of the Fourier spectrum.

Comment: @MartinBrown My question is about an odd-sized image because, in the ffshift function, I need to find the center of the image (which is easy in even-sized images).

Comment: OK. But you should remember that the FFT has strict periodic boundary conditions. Most FFTs and their inverses treat element y(0,0) as the DC component. Even transforms you always have 1,1,1,1,1,1... as DC and 1,-1,1,-1,1,-1... at (N/2,N/2)  as alternating components. Odd transforms you only have 1,1,1,1,1,1... - there is no alternating component the frequency information is held in complex conjugate pairs (which is why for real images most practitioners use complex conjugate symmetric transforms).  Consider the simplest case of N=3 to gain an insight...

Comment: @MartinBrown
Okay, but I encounter this issue of incorrect output only when using the fftshift function (after fft forward and befor fft inverse), not when using only fft forward + inverse (so without using fftshift function)

Comment: The other thing is that to resize the image (FFT people often call it oversampling) this way in the Fourier domain you simply zero pad the higher frequencies (at step 3).  That is you insert an extra band of zeros between components N/2 and (N+1)/2 to resize the image.  So  for N=2m or 2m+1 you insert zeroes to pad between cells m and m+1.  I don't know CUFFT's choice of scaling or layout but I'm assuming that IFT(FFT(image)) = image (possibly scaled by N.M) and give or take rounding errors in practice.  The the IFT of the larger Fourier domain data will interpolate on the new grid.